# Increasing the number of MAX485 nodes

Tags: rs485

I have two ports available to connect the RS485 dongle while a single RS485 dongle has a maximum of 32 node. I have 400 plus slaves to connect with RS485 so I want to know how can I connect multiple MAX485 IC with a single USB to UART IC (CH340G) so that I can connect 200 nodes on a single USB port. I have already checked about MAX1487 and I cannot use that because the slave has the MAX485 IC.

Comment: So you have 200 slaves all with MAX485 and you can't change that?

Comment: yes they all have max485 which can"t be change and I need to connect all 200 node with single USB port that means I have to handle at least 8 MAX485 with single usb to uart ic and we are following modbus rtu protocol.

Comment: "checked about MAX1487 and I cannot use that because the slave has the MAX485 IC" Huh? This does not make any sense. Yes, MAX1487 will not solve your problem, but it does not mean you cannot use it

Comment: Yes I can use that but it will not solve my problem because I have 200 nodes with single USB port and MAX485 physical limitation is 32.

Answer (score 0):

The MAX485 has Rin=12k, which limits the ports to 32.
The MAX487 has Rin=48k, which limits the ports to 128 but derated to 10th the bit rate due to expected parastic loads  (and 2500pF max load coax & parasitics) .

You won't be able to avoid repeaters and good cable but you have a problem with 200 nodes using MAX485. It looks like you need a better solution and more details on your physical topology, PHY choices and cable type.

120 Ohm UTP AWG28 is good for about 1MHz per km but 32 loads @ 12k adds a loading factor that exceeding this requires careful review of signal integrity.

If you can imagine the issues, you can simulate it.